# How to Access Dapper Results When Using Dynamic Due to Enum

Tags: c#, dynamic, dapper

I have a Dapper DB call that has a column that maps to an enum on the type. From what I understand, I have to query using dynamic because the query can't map to my `Request` type since `Status` is an enum on it. So I tried using this:

```
public async Task<Request> GetByRequestId(long id)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Request WHERE ID = @id";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        // Need dynamic here because of the conversion of the Status column as an enum.
        // If someone has a better way...
        dynamic dynamicRequest = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync(sql, new { id });
        if (dynamicRequest == null) { return default; }

        var request = new Request
        {
            Id = dynamicRequest.ID,
            Status = (RequestStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RequestStatus), dynamicRequest.Status)
        };

        return request;
    }
}
```

However, I can't access any of the properties on the dynamic object, called `dynamicRequest`. When debugging, I can see its value like this:

```
{{DapperRow, ID = '8', FooID = '12', Status = 'N'}}
```

How can I access `ID`, or `FooID`, or `Status`? This doesn't work:

```
dynamicRequest.ID
dynamicRequest[0]
dynamicRequest["ID"]
// and many other tries...
```

This is the error I get if I try using the actual class, instead of dynamic:

> System.Data.DataException   HResult=0x80131501   Message=Error parsing
>   column 4 (Status=N - String) ArgumentException: Requested value 'N'
>   was not found.

And this is the enum. I just added the `JsonConverter` attribute to try and get this to work with the actual `Request` class.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum RequestStatus
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "N")]
    New = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "A")]
    Approved = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = "C")]
    Cancelled = 3,

    [EnumMember(Value = "D")]
    Declined = 4,

    [EnumMember(Value = "P")]
    Pending = 5,
}
```

Here is a screenshot of `dynamicRequest` and an attempt at accessing the ID property.

[image]

Comment: Id personally change your string field to integer in the db and ditch the dynamic completely (assuming you can)

Comment: I may be able to do that, but the code in my post would work if I could just get access to `dynamicRequest`. I can see the values in the debugger.

Comment: So you just want to inspect/change them when debugging?

Comment: No, I want to create a proper `Request` object from the return value of the query and have the method return it. If I figure out how to access the values in the debugger (immediate window), that will help me do it in code.

Comment: What happens if you take out the Enum parse hooey, does it then map your other fields?

Comment: No. The enum parse isn't the issue (yet). I can't access any of the values on `dynamicRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `Enum.Parse` doesn't honor your `EnumMember` attributes.

This works however.

```cs
public static async Task<Request> GetByRequestId(long id)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Request WHERE ID = @id";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        // Need dynamic here because of the conversion of the Status column as an enum.
        // If someone has a better way...
        dynamic dynamicRequest = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync(sql, new { id });
        if (dynamicRequest == null) { return default; }

        var request = new Request
        {
            Id     = dynamicRequest.ID,
            Status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestStatus>($"\"{dynamicRequest.Status}\""),
        };

        return request;
    }
}
```

Running I get...

[image]

Then the mapped Request...

[image]

This is what my database table looks like...

[image]

Comment: The problem isn't trying to parse the status. I can't even get to that. From my post:

However, I can't access any of the properties on the dynamic object, called dynamicRequest. When debugging, I can see its value like this:

{{DapperRow, ID = '8', FooID = '12', Status = 'N'}}

Comment: Ah, you are probably right. I actually just accessed the ID property from `dynamicRequest` when I had it on its own line. Let me see about getting the `Status` property your way now...